# Beta site and invitations

Tags: web, beta, beta-testing

I'm launching a startup web site, what i would like to know is how to start with that, i mean is better to use invitations first of all?

Then how to send invitations and to who?

How can i plan invitations? Which are best practices?

Does anyone is passed from this step with his own site?

Any experience on here?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you create a beta version of the site first is completely up to you.

It really depends what type of website you're planning to make. Beta's are obviously a good way to gain feedback on your website and its functionality before releasing to everyone. Thus, allowing you to make improvements/fix bugs before everyone uses the site.

In terms of actually getting users for the beta, it's very much a case of marketing your website and its existence well (through social media, advertising etc.), and then providing some kind of 'sign up for the beta' page. You could then close registration for the beta once you have enough users, and devise some method of gaining feedback from users.

I haven't personally created a beta myself, but if I was to do it, I would do the above.

Hope that's of some help.

Comment: just i would like to know more opinions so i let the post open ;)